# What languages have a while-else type control structure, and how does it work?

Tags: programming-languages, for-loop, language-features, if-statement

A long time ago, I thought I saw a proposal to add an `else` clause to `for` or `while` loops in C or C++... or something like that.  I don't remember how it was supposed to work -- did the `else` clause run if the loop exited normally but not via a break statement?

Anyway, this is tough to search for, so I thought maybe I could get some CW answers here for various languages.

What languages support adding an `else` clause to something other than an `if` statement?  What is the meaning of that clause?  One language per answer please.

Answer (score 10):

[Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-while_stmt).

Example use:

```
for element in container:
  if element == target:
    break
else:
  # this will not be executed if the loop is quit with break.
  raise ElementNotFoundError()
```

From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> it is executed when the loop
>   terminates through exhaustion of the
>   list (with for) or when the condition
>   becomes false (with while), but not
>   when the loop is terminated by a break
>   statement.

Answer (score 3):

There is so-called "Dijkstra's Loop" (also called "Dijkstra's Guarded Loop"). It was defined in [The Guarded Command Language (GCL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language). You can find some information about it syntax and semantic in the above Wikipedia article at the section [6 Repetition: do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language#Repetition:_do).

Nowadays I actually know one programming language which supports this control struture directly. It is [Oberon-07](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/wirth/Articles/Oberon/Oberon07.Report.pdf) (PDF, 70 KB). And it supports "Dijkstra's Loop" in thу form of while statement. Take a look at section 9.6. While statements in the above PDF.

```
WHILE m > n DO m := m – n 
ELSIF n > m DO n := n – m 
END
```

Comment: Interesting... seems more like an `ELSEWHILE` than an `ELSIF`.  Definitely different semantics from the Python use of while-else.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: More details on the Oberon usage [here](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/wirth/Articles/Oberon/PortingOberon.pdf):  
The while statement has been extended according to the suggestion of the late Edsger Dijkstra. 
Note that it terminates, when all conditions are FALSE. This facility may, for example, be used to 
express the following loop construct: 
LOOP 
 IF b0 THEN S0 
 ELSIF b1 THEN S1 
 ELSIF b2 THEN S2 
 ELSE EXIT 
 END 
END 
in a simpler way, without nesting: 
WHILE b0 DO S0 
ELSIF b1 DO S1 
ELSIF b2 DO S2 
END

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, neither the Python or the Oberon construct are the one I've been searching for.  In C, I frequently find myself often wanting an 'otherwise' or 'elsewhile' construct that is executed only if the loop was never taken.  Perhaps this is the construction you are looking for as well?

So instead of:

```
if (condition) {
   do {
       condition = update(something);
   } while (condition);  
} else {
   loop_never_taken(something);
}
```

I could write:

```
while (condition) {
    condition = update(something);
} otherwhile {
    loop_never_taken(something);
}
```

It's definitely shorter, and I would find it much clearer to read.  It even translates easily into (pseudo) assembly:

```
    while: test condition
           bz elsewhile
     loop: push something    
           call update
     test: test condition
           bnz loop
           jmp done         
elsewhile: push something
           call loop_never_taken
     done: ...
```

I feel like it's a basic enough structure that it deserves a little more sugar.  But apparently there haven't been any successful language designers who rely on this structure as much as I do.  I wonder how much I should read into that!

Comment: I agree -- I think this is what I was hoping for 2 years ago, for whatever code I was writing at the time. Python's while-else (or for-else) doesn't parse right to me. I think while-then would make more sense: you do the loop, and *then* you do the then-clause. You could even have a while-then-else, where the "then" executes after the loop, the "else" executes if the loop was never entered, and both are skipped if a break statement is hit.